# How to improve antispam function discord.py?

Tags: datetime, discord, discord.py, message, spam-prevention

I'm making a discord bot and I have antispam function build in, but I want to improve it. I don't want this function to react to certain roles, like admin or moderator (so I want this function NOT to react to certain roles, so admins can spam). Also I have spam channel where I don't want this function to work, how do I do that? And last, but not least: how do I delete the same (spammed) messages? Because what my bot does is: it says "Stop spamming". But I want to delete the same message. Thank you very much! I hope you can help me!

THE CODE:

```py
    import os
    import discord
    import datetime
    
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
    
    time_window_milliseconds = 5000
    max_msg_per_window = 5
    author_msg_times = {}
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(ctx): #spam allowed in channel and for admins? How to make?
    
      global author_msg_counts
    
      author_id = ctx.author.id
      curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000
    
      if not author_msg_times.get(author_id, False):
          author_msg_times[author_id] = []
    
      author_msg_times[author_id].append(curr_time)
    
      expr_time = curr_time - time_window_milliseconds
    
      expired_msgs = [
          msg_time for msg_time in author_msg_times[author_id]
          if msg_time < expr_time
      ]
      for msg_time in expired_msgs:
          author_msg_times[author_id].remove(msg_time)
    
      if len(author_msg_times[author_id]) > max_msg_per_window:
        await ctx.delete(ctx)
        await ctx.send("Stop Spamming")
    
      else:
        print("You are good to go!")
              
    bot.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question about roles, you should add at the start of your spam check:

```
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
    return
```

This will make it not affect any member who has the permission to delete messages (this would be moderators or admins).

You can also do

```
if ctx.channel.id == [id here]:
    return
```

replacing [id here] with the id of your spam channel.
Lastly, put `await ctx.send("Stop Spamming")` before `await ctx.delete(ctx)`, and make sure your bot has permission to delete messages.